# Tips for nailing aluminum fascia cover

Tags: roofing

I noticed the other day while replacing some shingles that the aluminum covering my fascia board was bent a bit.  I think part of the problem was I sparingly used the soffit nails to attach it, and kept them high to avoid any possible drips.  It looks to me if I just added a nail lower where it bent out everything should be fine.  This led me to a few minute details on fascia nailing which I thought I'd ask.

1) Should the nails be kind of loose to let the fascia float a bit?  My understanding on siding was that you don't want to nail it down too tight, is fascia done the same?  I'm wondering if a bit of the bend was from nailing it too tight

2) Should I keep the nails high when nailing it?  If they are lower, should I be going back over with a good exterior caulk it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ideally you should punch the fascia with a slotted punch then set the aluminum nail loose so the fascia is free to expand and contract without buckling. Nail about 1 inch from the top and also on the bottom of the horizontal bend to hold the bottom in. This works for vinyl too.